# Should I release the object in this method?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Here is the code:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone {
    ExecutedOrderInfo* copy = [[self class] allocWithZone:zone];
    copy.executedPrice = self.executedPrice;
    copy.executedQuantity = self.executedQuantity;
    return (id)copy;
}
```

The question is, is it necessary to release "copy" in above code? Or release it when someone called it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not in this method. Methods that start with `copy` must return non-autorleased objects with retain count 1. Just as you do.

PS: the cast in `return (id)copy` is not needed. `id` is the abstract object type and much more general than your concrete class. Casts are only needed when having a concrete class that should be treated as a different one -- like a subclass after doing a subclass check.

PPS: Your method lacks an `init`. It's not good to just `alloc` a instance. Instead do something like this: `[[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];`

Comment: thanks Max, this helps a lot to me. and also thank you for using simple English..

Answer (score 0):

Max is right.
But all design and intend depend on you.
(Even if generally copyXXX means return non-autoreleased object)

And to prevent memory leaks, use Statics Analysis and Instruments after using it.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm reading your code correctly - No. The method doesn't create the object so it doesn't need to release it.

Comment: ExecutedOrderInfo* copy = [[self class] allocWithZone:zone]

you see this?

Comment: the `allocWithZone:` method actually is a object creation.

Comment: Doh! Was reading that as a factory method, not a create. Yep your right. This needs an init.